# density plot on a sphere Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

How to plot density map on the surface of a sphere if I have array of values corresponding to given (theta,phi) points in spherical coordinates? I have found how to construct a sphere e.g. [Bloch sphere](https://qutip.googlecode.com/svn/doc/2.0.0/html/guide/guide-bloch.html) or [plotting on a sphere](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/bender.astro.sunysb.edu/classes/python-science/lectures/matplotlib-basics.ipynb). The first example is really nice  looking - axes are needed and heatmap.

Comment: We're gonna need more info. Do you want it to be just a spherical plot coloured with the intensity of the density? Or do you want it to change R at the point corresponding to the density? (i'd recommend the former). If you want the plot to be interactive, i've had much better results with MayaVi. If you just want stationary plots from particular view angles, then matplotlib should be fine.

Comment: Also, what have you tried? Do you have a file with the data in that we can play with?

Comment: I tried to put a Mathematica graphics, but I do not have enough reputation points to do that - It is just a sphere with heatmap on it. I was thinking about custom coloring the sphere with values corresponding to the data points. do You know how to create this nice looking sphere in [Bloch sphere](https://qutip.googlecode.com/svn/doc/2.0.0/html/guide/guide-bloch.html)?

Comment: Include the link, someone will edit in the image for you.

Comment: You might be able to do this by altering the `Bloch` class - it uses `plot_surface` , which means you can pass it a "facr_colors` kwarg, and set the colours or the faces yourself. Are you looking to get a plot like [this](http://i.imgur.com/qHelsi1.png)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you subclass the `Bloch` class of `QuTip`, and alter the way it draws the sphere, you can draw density plots and keep all the other framework it creates.

Taking the [`matplotlib surface_plot` examples](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots), and altering the `Bloch` class' plotting functions works. Putting it in your own subclass prevents you from hacking away at the libraries.

```
from qutip import Bloch
from math import sqrt, sin, cos, pi
from colorsys import hsv_to_rgb


from numpy import linspace, outer, ones, sin, cos, arccos, arctan2, size, empty
class BlochDensity(Bloch):
  def plot_back(self):
    # back half of sphere
    u = linspace(0, pi, 25)
    v = linspace(0, pi, 25)
    x = outer(cos(u), sin(v))
    y = outer(sin(u), sin(v))
    z = outer(ones(size(u)), cos(v))

    colours = empty(x.shape, dtype=object)
    for i in range(len(x)):
      for j in range(len(y)):
        theta = arctan2(y[i,j], x[i,j])
        phi = arccos(z[i,j])

        colours[i,j] = self.density(theta, phi)


    self.axes.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=1, cstride=1,
                           facecolors=colours,
                           alpha=self.sphere_alpha, 
                           linewidth=0, antialiased=True)
    # wireframe
    self.axes.plot_wireframe(x, y, z, rstride=5, cstride=5,
                             color=self.frame_color,
                             alpha=self.frame_alpha)
    # equator
    self.axes.plot(1.0 * cos(u), 1.0 * sin(u), zs=0, zdir='z',
                   lw=self.frame_width, color=self.frame_color)
    self.axes.plot(1.0 * cos(u), 1.0 * sin(u), zs=0, zdir='x',
                   lw=self.frame_width, color=self.frame_color)



  def plot_front(self):
    # front half of sphere
    u = linspace(-pi, 0, 25)
    v = linspace(0, pi, 25)
    x = outer(cos(u), sin(v))
    y = outer(sin(u), sin(v))
    z = outer(ones(size(u)), cos(v))

    colours = empty(x.shape, dtype=object)
    for i in range(len(x)):
      for j in range(len(y)):
        theta = arctan2(y[i,j], x[i,j])
        phi = arccos(z[i,j])

        colours[i,j] = self.density(theta, phi)


    self.axes.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=1, cstride=1,
                           facecolors=colours,
                           alpha=self.sphere_alpha, 
                           linewidth=0, antialiased=True)


    # wireframe
    self.axes.plot_wireframe(x, y, z, rstride=5, cstride=5,
                             color=self.frame_color,
                             alpha=self.frame_alpha)
    # equator
    self.axes.plot(1.0 * cos(u), 1.0 * sin(u),
                   zs=0, zdir='z', lw=self.frame_width,
                   color=self.frame_color)
    self.axes.plot(1.0 * cos(u), 1.0 * sin(u),
                   zs=0, zdir='x', lw=self.frame_width,
                   color=self.frame_color)
```

What i've done here is make the plotting part call the function of `BlochDensity`: `self.density(theta, phi)` - which i haven't defined.

After you create the `BlochDensity` object, you need to create that function, which is the mapping of `theta, phi` onto your density. I would advise using [SciPy's 2D interpolation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html) to create the function, something like this:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d
from numpy.random import rand

b = BlochDensity()
b.sphere_alpha=0.5

thetas, phis = linspace(-pi,pi,10), linspace(0,pi,10)
density = rand(len(thetas), len(phis))

#scale density to a maximum of 1
density /= density.max()

interpolated_density = interp2d(thetas, phis, density)

def f(theta, phi):
  return hsv_to_rgb(interpolated_density(theta,phi), 1, 1)

b.density = f

b.show()

b.density = f

b.show()
```

[image]

If you want to increase the resolution, then just change the numbers in the linspace inside the `plot_*` functions of `BlochDensity`.

Comment: just realised the demo image at the bottom would look way better in terms of a density plot if the values in the linspace were smaller, so there were fewer lobes. Try reducing it to see what it looks like.